# Shortest time for $C$ distinct objects to arrive

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

> Assume there are $N+1$ objects denoted by $O_1,O_2,...,O_{N+1}$, and each object has an arrival process. The first $N$ of them arrive with rate $\lambda_i,~i=\{1,2,...,N\}$, and $O_{N+1}$ arrive with rate $\mu$. Let $X_i$ denote the inter-arrival time of the $i$-th object (keep in mind that each object has an arrival process, and the inter-arrival time means the time between two adjacent same objects), and let $Y$ denote the inter-arrival time for object $O_{N+1}$. All the inter-arrival times are exponentially distributed.
>
> Question: think of the situation that, starting from any time epoch, there are at least $C$ **distinct** ($C$ is a constant) objects arrive before object $O_{N+1}$ arrives. If this case happens, find the time duration $\tau$, during which the first $C$ **distinct** objects arrive.
>
> Extra info: By definition, $\tau$ is a random variable, but current research has verified that it can be regarded as a **constant**.

My analysis: for object $O_i$ that belongs to  the $C$ objects, its inter-arrival time $X_i$ must be smaller than $Y$ ($X_i<Y$), and $\tau$ must be between $X_i$ and $Y$ ($X_i<\tau<Y$). Then define an indicator function $I_i$, $I_i=1$ if $\tau$ satisfies $X_i<\tau<Y$ on condition that $X_i<Y$, otherwise $I_i=0$, so we have $\sum_{i=1}^N I_i=C$. Taking average on both sides, we get $\sum_{i=1}^N E[I_i]=\sum_{i=1}^N P(X_i<\tau<Y|X_i<Y) = C$. If I have the expression for $P(X_i<\tau<Y|X_i<Y) = C$, maybe I can get $\tau$.

Unfortunately, this analysis is not correct according to my simulation. Can someone tell me how to analyze this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: What is meant by "time duration"?  To what does it apply - the $C$ distinct object arrival times, or $Y$?

Comment: @jbowman It means the time duration needed for $C$ distinct objects to arrive, starting from any time epoch.

Comment: So $\tau$ is the max of the arrival times of the first $C$ distinct objects that arrive before object $O_{N+1}$, of course given that $C$ distinct objects actually do arrive before $O_{N+1}$.

Comment: @jbowman Exactly. In a more concise way, among the variables $X_1, X_2,..., X_N, Y$, when $Y$ ranks $C+1$ or higher (in ascending order), find the arrival time of the object that ranks $C$.

Comment: @jbowman Any idea?